# Is it guaranteed that bitwise "and" for bool does not short circuit?

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style, language-lawyer

I recently came across a code snippet that looked like this:

```
bool MyClass::do_work()
{
    bool success = true;
    for (auto const& worker : m_workers)
    {
        success &= worker.do_work();  // worker.do_work() returns a bool
    }
    return success;
}
```

If I understand it correctly, the function returns `true` if all workers return `true` and it returns `false` if any worker returns false. However, it always evaluates all workers (which is desired). There is no short-circuit evaluation involved, since the bitwise operator `&=` was used and not the logical operator `&&`.

Is this behavior guaranteed? To be exact, is it guaranteed that bitwise `&` always evaluates both operands, even if they are of type `bool`? I came across many SO answers regarding guaranteed short-circuit evaluation for `&&`, but none of them state that there is guaranteed non-short-circuit evaluation for `&`.

If this behavior is guaranteed, is this a good programming style? It took me more than a quick glance to understand the function, because I have not seen this style before, and at first I was confused whether short-circuit evaluation was involved or not.

Is there a better alternative than the following?

```
bool MyClass::do_work()
{
    bool success = true;
    for (auto const& worker : m_workers)
    {
        if (!worker.do_work())
        {
            success = false;
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: I'd say it's a very confusing style: it seems easy to overlook the no-short-circuit effect.

Comment: All the operands of an operator are usually evaluated, `&&`, `||` and `?:` operators are exceptions. The standard even mentions for `&&` that *"Unlike `&`, `&&` guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is `false`."*. As for if this is good programming style, this is opinion-based.

Comment: @You I don't think the standard guarantees that `all_of` does not perform short-circuit, that would be really strange.

Comment: @Holt How is `all_of` related to the bitwise `&`?

Comment: @Holt: I realized this approx. 3 seconds after posting :)

Comment: @pschill I was answering a now-deleted comment from [You](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147845/you) ;)

Comment: "Is there a better alternative [...]?" [Some](https://sean-parent.stlab.cc/presentations/2013-09-11-cpp-seasoning/cpp-seasoning.pdf) would argue, yes(?): `std::count_if(m_workers.begin(), m_workers.end(), [](const auto& worker) { return !worker.do_work(); }) == 0;`

Comment: Or `success = worker.do_work() && success;` if you want to stick with an imperative loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless explicitly specified by the standard, all  operands of an operator are evaluated and unsequenced<sup>1</sup> in C++:

> [[intro.execution]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.exec#intro.execution-10)
>
> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.
>   [...]
>   The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator. [...]

The only three exceptions that come to my mind are the `&&`, `||` and `?:` operators<sup>2</sup>.

The standard even mentions for `&&`<sup>3</sup> that:

> [[expr.log.and]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.log.and)
>
> Unlike `&`, `&&` guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is `false`.

As for if this is good programming style, this is opinion-based.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Unsequenced basically means that if you have `A @ B` (where `@` is an operator), `B` (and its side effects) can be evaluated before `A`, which is why construct such as [`i++ + ++i` are undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior).</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Note that for overloaded `&&` and `||` operator, this is not true anymore since both operands are evaluated. `?:` cannot be overloaded.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> There is a similar note for `|` within [[expr.log.or]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.log.or).</sub>

Comment: _Unlike `&`, `&&` guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is `false`_. Let me rephrase that: _`&` does not guarantee left-to-right evaluation._ Unfortunately, this statement means that the `&` operator may perform short-circuit evaluation, it just isnt guaranteed.

Comment: @pschill No, it means that `&` can evaluate the right operand before the left one, as most operators. When you do `A op B`, `B` can be evaluated before `A`, but both will be evaluated, except for `&&`, `||` and `?:`.

Comment: @pschill The `||` version is a bit better if you'd prefer: *"Unlike |, || guarantees left-to-right evaluation; **moreover**, the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand evaluates to true."*

Comment: @pschill I've edited my answer to add the standard quote regarding the default behavior of operators that states that all operands of an operator are evaluated unless specified otherwise.

Comment: Okay, so the point is that operators (except `&&` etc) are evaluated like "normal" C++ functions, which means that all arguments are evaluated. Thank you :)